# PHP/Html file into a html file

Tags: php, html, file

I am a newbie in coding etc. so I am trying to get some help from you guys. I have to put every single file (.php) in one .html/php file.

Now I got this code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        span {
            text-decoration:underline;
            color:blue;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        // show the given page, hide the rest
        function show(elementID) {
            // try to find the requested page and alert if it's not found
            var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
            if (!ele) {
                alert("no such element");
                return;
            }

            // get all pages, loop through them and hide them
            var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
            for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
                pages[i].style.display = 'none';
            }

            // then show the requested page
            ele.style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
  <p>
    Show page 
        <span onClick="show('Page1');">1</span>, 
        <span onClick="show('Page2');">2</span>, 
        <span onClick="show('Page3');">3</span>.
    </p>

<div id="Page1" class="page" style="">
    Content of page 1
</div>
<div id="Page2" class="page" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
</div>
<div id="Page3" class="page" style="display:none">
    Content of page 3
</div>

</body>
```

So my question is; how do i put my files into the 'Content of page 1/2/3'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is javascript not php

Comment: Why do you have to do this?

Comment: You just need more of those `$("#includedContent").load("b.html");` pointing to the proper pages and using the proper DIV ids to load into.

Comment: My teacher told me to.. I have no idea why

Comment: This depends in the project type... does your teacher is asking to call the pages using ajax (javascript + server side script), or just include the file. If ajax you need javascript (if you can use a framework try jQuery.ajax()), if it is just including the file with php, just use Goudgeld1 answer.

Comment: Problem solved. Just had to use '<? include 'b.php'; ?>'. Thanks everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `include("[path to your file]");` or `include_once("[path to your file]");`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. He's asking to combine all the code into one file. This solution would still require multiple files.

Comment: @rick6 That is true, I didn't read the question properly but hopefully this answer will help other people :)

Comment: Totally. I actually started writing a similar answer to yours, then I re-read the question and changed my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to combine other PHP files with this HTML file, simply change the name of this file to `.php` if it isn't already. Then copy/paste your code (in order each file is processed) into the top of this file. Be sure to surround your php with `<?php` and `?>`. The HTML will still display correctly if it's inside a PHP file.

Note: This is not good practice, but it will accomplish what your teacher is requesting.